# can't install adminator admin dashboard using git

Tags: node.js, git, npm-install

this is my first time using git, I am trying to install adminator admin dashboard and I am following the rules and solve problems, but now this problem couldn't solve it from hours!! I am so confused and don't know what to do, can you help me please??

--when I type npm install everything go smoothly until this happening:

```
 ==> cwd: C:\Users\Zeineb\Adminator\node_modules\better-sqlite3
 ==> node-gyp rebuild
 C:\Users\Zeineb\Adminator\node_modules\better-sqlite3>if not defined 
 npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Zeineb\Adminator\node_modules\better-
 sqlite3\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node 
 "" rebuild )
 Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel 
 build, please add the "/m" switch.
 unpack_sqlite_dep
 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 C:\Program Files 
 (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): 
 error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exi
 ted with code 1. [C:\Users\Zeineb\Adminator\node_modules\better-
 sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]
 gyp ERR! build error
 gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` 
 failed with exit code: 1
 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
 (C:\Users\Zeineb\Adminator\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
 gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
 (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
 gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
 gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
 "C:\\Users\\Zeineb\\Adminator\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" 
 "rebuild"
 gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Zeineb\Adminator\node_modules\better-sqlite3
 gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.0
 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
 gyp ERR! not ok
 Error: exit code 1
 at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Zeineb\Adminator\node_modules\lzz-
 gyp\lib\exec.js:19:12)
 at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
```

and at the end of the installation this is written :

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this 
file.
npm WARN postcss-html@0.11.0 requires a peer of postcss-sass@>=0.2.0 but 
none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 
(node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: better-sqlite3@4.0.3 
(node_modules\better-sqlite3):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: better-sqlite3@4.0.3 
install: `node deps/install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

I am using windows 10 , npm v 5.5.1

Comment: [this is the source](https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard)

Comment: Do you have python on your machine ?

Comment: Yes, I installed it ver 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!

I first tried to install Python via git, it didn't install or I did something wrong since I am a newbie at git environment, so I installed it via visual studio, and put the following into path environment variables :

```
 1)C:\Python27amd64
 2)C:\Python27amd64\Lib\site-packages\
 3)C:\Python27amd64\Scripts
```

Now everything is working totally fine, all thanks to @TGrif for making me re-check the Python thing.